# For loop in `define Macro

Tags: verilog, hdl

I searched on SO, and on web, no where found the ans.
I have following code, where It success fully parsed `define and generate expected results, but if number of times calling of macro is large then, Can we using ***Looping Construct?***.

```
`define myreg(name) \
   addr_``name    

`define para(i) \
  parameter `myreg(i) = i  

module register;

`para(1);
`para(2);
`para(3);
`para(4);

initial
begin
  $display("ADDR1 = %d, ADDR2 = %d", addr_1, addr_2);
  $display("ADDR3 = %d, ADDR4 = %d", addr_3, addr_4);
  #100 $finish;
end
endmodule
```

Simulation Result:

```
// # Loading work.register(fast)
// # run -all
// # ADDR1 =           1, ADDR2 =           2
// # ADDR3 =           3, ADDR4 =           4
// # ** Note: $finish    : reg.v(18)
```

Now, when I use ***for loop***, like in below code,

```
`define myreg(name) \
   addr_``name    

`define para(i) \
  parameter `myreg(i) = i  

module register;

genvar i;
generate 
  for (i = 1; i<=4; i=i+1)
  begin
    `para(i);
  end
endgenerate

initial
begin
  $display("ADDR1 = %d, ADDR2 = %d", addr_1, addr_2);
  $display("ADDR3 = %d, ADDR4 = %d", addr_3, addr_4);
  #100 $finish;
end
endmodule
```

In that case, It shows an error while displaying or using it,
Simulation Result:

```
// # vsim -lib work register -c -do "run -all; quit -f" -appendlog -l qverilog.log -vopt 
// # ** Note: (vsim-3813) Design is being optimized due to module recompilation...
// # ** Error (suppressible): (vopt-7063) reg.v(24): Failed to find 'addr_1' in hierarchical name '/addr_1'.
// # ** Error (suppressible): (vopt-7063) reg.v(24): Failed to find 'addr_2' in hierarchical name '/addr_2'.
// # ** Error (suppressible): (vopt-7063) reg.v(25): Failed to find 'addr_3' in hierarchical name '/addr_3'.
// # ** Error (suppressible): (vopt-7063) reg.v(25): Failed to find 'addr_4' in hierarchical name '/addr_4'.
// # Optimization failed
// # Error loading design
```

It is asked more times but proper solution is not given by any one, any help appreciated a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
generate
  for (i = 1; i<=4; i=i+1)
  begin
    addr_i = i;
  end
endgenerate
```

Macros are expanded at beginning of compilation. By the time "generate" is processed, the code is equivalent to above. The generate will result in a "addr_i" being assigned four times but not "addr_1", "addr_2", etc.

Comment: that doesn't give the solution to the OP's question